# Yanking to system clipboard does not work

Tags: vimrc, cut-copy-paste, os-clipboard, linux-ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, I have `+clipboard` and `+xterm_clipboard` in my `vim --version`, and I have set `set clipboard=unnamedplus` in my `.vimrc`.

For some reason, yanking still does not copy to the system buffer by default. I have the same setup on previous Linux machines as well as a Mac where pressing `y` on selected text copies it into the system clipboard. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is this terminal or gvim? are you possibly using ssh or some other "unusual" setup?

Comment: "pressing y on selected text copies it into the system clipboard" --> try `xnoremap y "+y`

Comment: This issue appears to happen only when Vim is suspended with Ctrl+Z.